# How to pass ET.dump() xml string from a Django view to a template -- python django ElementTree

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, elementtree

I would like to format a bit of XML and pass it to a Django template.  In the shell, I am able to successfully create the XML string using the following code:

```
locations = Location.objects.all()
industries = Industry.objects.all()

root = ET.Element("root")

    for industry in industries:
        doc = ET.SubElement(root, "industry")
        doc.set("name", industry.text)
        for location in locations:
            if industry.id == location.company.industry_id:
                item = ET.SubElement(doc, "item")
                latitude = ET.SubElement(item, "latitude")
                latitude.text = str(location.latitude)
                longitude = ET.SubElement(item, "longitude")
                longitude.text = str(location.longitude)
```

Then, still in the shell, `ET.dump(root)` outputs the XML I expect.

But, how can I use `ET.dump(root)` to pass the XML string from a Django view to a template file?

I have tried to pass it as `{{xml_items}}` using `'xml_items': ET.dump(root)` and I have also tried to assign `ET.dump(root)` to a variable and pass it like `'xml_items': xml_items`.

In both cases, the template outputs `None` for `{{xml_items}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dump` is just a debug function. You should use the `tostring` function:

```
ET.tostring(root)
```

which will give you exactly what ET.dump() prints, but as a string.

If you're using lxml, you can also use

```
ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

to get a better-looking XML, but if this is just going to be consumed by another code layer, then you don't really want that anyways. And it's not available in the stock ElementTree.